# Is there a page I can track all the stats of my all kinds of reviews?

Tags: support, review-queues

Every time I want to check my review progress today and in total, I have to choose one type of review in review queues, and click `stats` tab to see how many I review today.

For total progress, `Badge Progress` is next to tabs, but I still have to enter one particular review.

Is there a page or simple way to track all kinds of review progress for today and in total much easier?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Can I ask you why are checking progress at all? In competitive games seeing score is ok. Do you compete with somebody on SO or what is the purpose of such checks?

Comment: We know review job has 20/40 limit per day, when I do review jobs, I want to know how much work left today, for each type of review. But Currently the query is inconvenient, I have to click one by one. @Sinatr

Comment: And also I want to check the badge progress for each type of review, still I have to click one by one. @Sinatr

Comment: But why do you want to see those limits? Simply review blindly until it say "you are off limits" or until you loose interest/time. Same with badges or are you afraid of doing few extra reviews or what is the problem, why do you need to see exact numbers? I don't understand.

Comment: just check the progress when I take a break, I do this many times, so I want to find an easy way. maybe this requirement is not necessary because I am the only one @Sinatr

Comment: Hunting badges is fun, I'm not sure why it's looked down upon...